# How to go to next line while in MongoDB shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am taking a MongoDB course on Lynda and the instructor goes to a new line while entering javascript code. How is this accomplished? I am talking about the lines she went to with the ellipsis "..."[image]

Comment: ... represents new line. Copy paste the code into shell you would see the same

Comment: How do you go to the next line to even do that though without hitting enter?

Comment: its a new line character

Comment: Aha, I see! Thats awesome!

Answer (score 10):

If you end a line with an open parenthesis ('('), an open brace ('{'), or an open bracket ('['), then the subsequent lines start with ellipsis ("...") until you enter the corresponding closing parenthesis (')'), the closing brace ('}') or the closing bracket (']'). The mongo shell waits for the closing parenthesis, closing brace, or the closing bracket before evaluating the code, as in the following example:

```
> if ( x > 0 ) {
... count++;
... print (x);
... }
```

The can find more details on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#multi-line-operations-in-the-mongo-shell